# Chromium Portable is missing Google API-Key

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, api

I use [Chromium Portable](http://crportable.sourceforge.net/) on Windows in an environment that does not save stuff beyond reboot. On every start of the program it complains about some missing API-Key (see screenshot in german). The learn-more link leads to the [chromium wiki page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) where the first requirement for getting such a key says `Make sure you are a member of chromium-dev@chromium.org` which kind of tells me that this not what I want as I only want to *use* that browser. I went through a couple of releases of this portable package and it is there for quite a while without me configuring anything. Is this something the package maintainers forgot to turn off? How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug with the current release.  Verify the problem exists in the previous release, if its not present, report the problem.

Comment: You only need to subscribe to that mailing list to access the API and generate API keys.

Comment: https://github.com/ezeeyahoo/ChromiumSyncEnabler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just three years later I actually found out that it's as easy as defining

```
export GOOGLE_API_KEY=""
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=""
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=""
```

in your `~/.profile` to get rid of this warning.

My [source](https://gist.github.com/cvan/44a6d60457b20133191bd7b104f9dcc4) to this also has a solution for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From the Chromium Portable Help.html:

> Chromium Portable has a few settings that affect the behavior of the launcher and of the browser. They can be set by creating a file named ChromiumPortable.ini alongside ChromiumPortable.exe.
>
> The ChromiumPortable.ini file is composed of lines in the key=value format. Valid keys are listed below.

```
[...]    
GoogleAPIKeys=<api key> :: <client id> :: <client secret>
```

> Access keys for the Google APIs. More details are available at the Chromium development website. Note that the delimiters (::) are surrounded by a single space on each side.

Create your API keys as described here (http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) and create the ini file to use them in Chromium Portable.
Worked for me! Sync is active now.

Comment: Do you create a new ChromiumPortable.ini and disregard the one in PortableApps\ChromiumPortable\App\AppInfo\Launcher?

Comment: Okay I guess so, since that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Portable X-Chromium 37.0.2007.0 does NOT have this issue.

http://www.winpenpack.com/en/download.php?view.1082

Just download and run.